# In Distributed testing results folders are created per user or thread

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

I am running into the following strange issue.

**Issue** In Distributed testing results folders are created per user or thread.
Test has been  executed from master machine with  One Slave machine.

Both machines have same version of java8.

**Actual Results** 4 Results has been created. 2 of folders has Aggregate Report and ViewTree results files. 2 of folders has just ViewTable Results files.

**Expected Results** Supposed to be created just One folder with Aggregate Report,View Tree and View Table results files.

Any one has encounter this issue?I am not sure what went wrong,please advise.

Below are the screenshots of Master and Slave machine settings.

**Below  screenshot shows the configuration of Master Machine**
[image]

**Below  screenshot shows the configuration of Slave Machine**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply don't use JMeter Listeners for anything but tests development and debugging. When it comes to running your test make sure you have any listeners deleted from the test plan (or at least disabled) as they are don't add any value, the only thing they do is [consuming your JMeter load generators resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing).

Just run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -R slave1, slave2, slave3 -l result.jtl
```

Once your test will be finished you will either be able to open this `result.jtl` file with the listener of your choice or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of it.

See [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) User Manual chapter for more details.

Comment: ,I would like have ViewResultsInTable csv also in the provided above command line with the jtl .How can I do that.

Comment: 1. Open JMeter GUI. 2. Add [View Results in Table](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) listener. 3. Click "Browse" button. 4. Locate `results.jtl` file 5. Voila, you have the results.